# Configuring Mongo DB mapping from bundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, bundle

I'm trying to set up a bundle which would provide the config for mapping of the entities in the bundle.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
         default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: questions
    document_managers:
        default: ~
```

And then In the bundle:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    document_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                TwoBitQuestionnaireBundle:
                    type: yml
                    prefix: TwoBit\Questionnaires\Model
```

I hoped this would work, but instead I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 404:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_mongodb" 
(in /home/vagrant/sites/questions/src/TwoBit/QuestionnaireBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). 
Looked for namespace "doctrine_mongodb", found none
```

Comment: You have not bundle installed, add bundle to `AppKernel.php` if you installed it with composer.

Comment: I load the bundle ( first DoctrineMongoDBBundle, then my bundle ).

Comment: Ok, so you cannot just write another bundle config in your bundle file without any modifications, look: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html